# Remove space at the beginning of an unordered list when using inline-block li elements

Tags: html, css

Hi friends (and creatures of the internet), I have another question for you all today. Keep in mind I am relatively new to web design so the answer could be quite simple.

I have this social media icons list at the top left of my screen, within my navigation bar. I am using an unordered list and have the list elements using `display: inline-block;` to display my elements in a horizontal fashion.

It is working fine (for the most part) and looks like this: 
[image]

CSS:

```
#topFixedNavBar .tfnb_list {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 32px;
    margin: 0;
}

#topFixedNavBar .tfnb_list_item {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "topFixedNavBar">
            <div class = "tfnb_content">
                    <ul class = "tfnb_list">
                        <li class = "tfnb_list_item" id = "tfnb_list_item_facebookIcon">
                            <img class = "tfnb_list_item_facebookIcon_img" src="images/facebook-icon-preview.png"/>
                        </li>
                        <li class = "tfnb_list_item" id = "tfnb_list_item_youtubeIcon">
                            <img class = "tfnb_list_item_youtubeIcon_img" src="images/YouTube_Play.png"/>
                        </li>
                        <li class = "tfnb_list_item" id = "tfnb_list_item_instagramIcon">
                            <img class = "tfnb_list_item_instagramIcon_img" src="images/Instagram-logo-round.png"/>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
</div>
```

Except... you see that space between the left margin and the facebook icon? I have been trying to get rid of it in the most responsible way a web developer can--but simply giving the `<ul>` element a negative margin and calling it a day is not satisfying the perfectionist within me. Any help here?

Thanks

Comment: It probably also has a default padding that you should set to 0. Add `padding:0` to `#topFixedNavBar .tfnb_list`

Comment: set the padding and the margin on the `ul` to `0`

Comment: `ul` elements have a default padding so that the bullets will not end up outside the list, this is most probably it, just remove the padding. You should learn to use DevTools to debug this yourself, it will help you reduce the time you take solving this kind of issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `padding-left:0`  to get rid of the space on the left in your div with class`.tfnb_list`

```css
#topFixedNavBar .tfnb_list {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 32px;
  margin: 0;
}
#topFixedNavBar .tfnb_list_item {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.tfnb_list{
border:solid red;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="topFixedNavBar">
  <div class="tfnb_content">
    <ul class="tfnb_list">
      <li class="tfnb_list_item" id="tfnb_list_item_facebookIcon">
        <img class="tfnb_list_item_facebookIcon_img" src="images/facebook-icon-preview.png" />
      </li>
      <li class="tfnb_list_item" id="tfnb_list_item_youtubeIcon">
        <img class="tfnb_list_item_youtubeIcon_img" src="images/YouTube_Play.png" />
      </li>
      <li class="tfnb_list_item" id="tfnb_list_item_instagramIcon">
        <img class="tfnb_list_item_instagramIcon_img" src="images/Instagram-logo-round.png" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First comment on my post had my solution, but ty for this anyways!

Answer (score 1):

For ul give style like

```
#topFixedNavBar .tfnb_list { position: relative; max-height: 32px; margin: 0;padding-left: 0; }
```

Comment: This is gr8 too... :D